# Bulk add quotes to SQL values

Tags: sql-server

Not sure if this is an appropriate "programming" issue but its relevant.
Is there a way via SQL or excel even to  add quotes  to a big number of values,  for example i want to add values a,b,c,d,e,f,g,j etc etc to a table is there a way i can automatically add quotes to them? as in 'a','b' etc...

i have this issue especially in my select * from table  where column in ('value1','value2')...

Thanks...

Comment: Please be more specific, whether you want to add quotes to the value of column, or want to add value to the column?

Comment: Where are you getting your values from exactly? A text file? A query? An Excel file?

Comment: copy paste  from a diffent table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure if this helps or is what you were asking, but for such queries you should use parameters, i.e. something like

```
SELECT ... WHERE column IN (?,?)
```

This is not only an easy approach, but also means that if somebody puts a single-quote in the value they give you, the form of your query can't be altered - that's how SQL Injection security attacks happen.

Comment: @ adrian not what i meant... i want a way to automatically add '' to my values rather than adding the quotes and the commas by hand...each time..

Answer (score 1):

I usually tackle this sort of issue using Excel - if you enter your source values in a column, you can then just use an Excel formula to concatenate the values with quotes around them (eg =CONCATENATE("'", A1, "'")), and even extend this to build the complete SQL statement.

Answer (score 0):

If you have values in the same column of another table you coud use a select query

```
select '''' + cast(ValueColumn as nvarchar) + '''' as QuotedVal from MyTable
```

and then do your copy/paste

Comment: I GET AN ERROR WITH that Error converting data type varchar to numeric.

Comment: Edited to works with numeric too (added the cast to nvarchar)